# Setting the Python path for the trunk version of Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run the unit tests for the trunk version of Django. I also have a version of Django installed on my system which I installed via `apt-get install`.

How can I change the Python path to point to the trunk version of Django ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From bash (or other shell) you can manipulate the $PYTHONPATH to point to the parent directory, e.g.,
`echo $PYTHONPATH`
`export PYTHONPATH="/newhome/django_x.x/trunk"`

This will *prepend* the paths given to the existing python path list.

[python.org](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#search-path) :

> For example, if PYTHONPATH is set to
>   `/www/python:/opt/py`, the search path
>   will begin with
>
> ```
> ['/www/python','/opt/py']
> ```
>
> (Note that directories
>   must exist in order to be added to
>   sys.path; the site module removes
>   paths that don’t exist.)

From within python, you can also change sys.path (`import sys` if you haven't) to point to your testing branch.

Example from [python.org](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#search-path) :

```
$ python
Python 2.2 (#11, Oct  3 2002, 13:31:27)
[GCC 2.96 20000731 (Red Hat Linux 7.3 2.96-112)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.3', '/usr/local/lib/python2.3/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.3/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.3/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.3/site-packages']
>>>
```

To add a path, use something like :

```
sys.path.append('/workingdir/python/')
```

A Django-centric example from [djangotricks](http://djangotricks.blogspot.com/2008/09/note-on-python-paths.html) (blog) :

```
import os, sys

SVN_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", ".."))
DJANGO_PATH = os.path.join(SVN_PATH, "django_src", "trunk")
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.join(SVN_PATH, "myproject", "trunk")

sys.path += [DJANGO_PATH, PROJECT_PATH]
```

---

Additionally, unless you've suppressed the behavior, python loads `site.py` on execution, so you can also edit the `site.py` file, e.g. `/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py` :

The comments of the `site.py` file are also instructive.

```
$ more /usr/lib/python2.7/site.py
```

> ```
> """Append module search paths for third-party packages to sys.path.
>
> ****************************************************************
> * This module is automatically imported during initialization. *
> ****************************************************************
>
> In earlier versions of Python (up to 1.5a3), scripts or modules that
> needed to use site-specific modules would place ``import site''
> somewhere near the top of their code.  Because of the automatic
> import, this is no longer necessary (but code that does it still
> works).
>
> This will append site-specific paths to the module search path.  On
> Unix (including Mac OSX), it starts with sys.prefix and
> sys.exec_prefix (if different) and appends
> lib/python<version>/site-packages as well as lib/site-python.
> On other platforms (such as Windows), it tries each of the
> prefixes directly, as well as with lib/site-packages appended.  The
> resulting directories, if they exist, are appended to sys.path, and
> also inspected for path configuration files.
>
> For Debian and derivatives, this sys.path is augmented with directories
> for packages distributed within the distribution. Local addons go
> into /usr/local/lib/python<version>/dist-packages,
> Debian addons
> install into /usr/{lib,share}/python<version>/dist-packages.
> /usr/lib/python<version>/site-packages
> is not used.
>
> A path configuration file is a file whose name has the form
> <package>.pth; its contents are additional directories (one per line)
> to be added to sys.path.  Non-existing directories (or
> non-directories) are never added to sys.path; no directory is added to
> sys.path more than once.  Blank lines and lines beginning with
> '#' are skipped. Lines starting with 'import' are executed.
>
> For example, suppose sys.prefix and sys.exec_prefix are set to
> /usr/local and there is a directory
> /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages
> with three subdirectories, foo, bar and spam, and two path
> configuration files, foo.pth and bar.pth.  Assume foo.pth contains the
> following:
>
>   # foo package configuration
>   foo
>   bar
>   bletch
>
> and bar.pth contains:
>
>   # bar package configuration
>   bar
>
> Then the following directories are added to sys.path, in this order:
>
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/bar
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/foo
>
> Note that bletch is omitted because it doesn't exist; bar precedes
> foo
> because bar.pth comes alphabetically before foo.pth; and
> spam is
> omitted because it is not mentioned in either path configuration
> file.
>
> After these path manipulations, an attempt is made to import a module
> named sitecustomize, which can perform arbitrary additional
> site-specific customizations.  If this import fails with an
> ImportError exception, it is silently ignored.
> ```

References:
[python.org docs, v2.7 search path](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#search-path)
[python.org docs, v3 search path](http://docs.python.org/py3k/install/index.html#search-path)
[Djangotricks blog, a note on python paths](http://djangotricks.blogspot.com/2008/09/note-on-python-paths.html)
[Martin Jansen : Django settings files for development and production](http://martinjansen.com/2008/10/20/django-settings-files-for-development-and-production/)

Answer (score 1):

Good question. You can solved this issue with python. Open python interpreter and

```
Python 2.6
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python24.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.4',
'/usr/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib/site-python']
```

To change the path, just append/prepend entries to sys.path, which is a normal
Python list, e.g.

```
>>> sys.path.append('/path/to/django/trunk')
>>> sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/django/trunk')
```

Either one of those command should add it to your path.

Comment: Well, at least our answers aren't completely redundant.  ;)

Comment: for what he wants to do; this is the proper way to do it. so at least some of our answers aren't completely wrong. :P

Comment: @dustyprogrammer  Hmm, I believe some of my info *was* wrong, at least according to python.org .   I have replaced that info and expanded.  I'm not a django user, so I've added a couple of django-centric references.

Comment: @jgbelacqua haha copying and pasting things from the google, will get you the information needed even without understanding. Now who is copying who? :)

Comment: @dusty I'm "copying" python.org and the other references I cited, but attempting to put them into terms that are useful for the OP and understandable to me.  I'm not sure why you find it necessary to be insulting.

Comment: I would again refer you back to your original comment.

Comment: @dusty That comment was made because our answers were posted within the same minute.  I apologize that I did not make clear that it was intended to be lighthearted.  A few hours later, I began to edit my answer, and continued doing so far a bit, and as a result, the text of my answer was different.  The answer is for the OP, not for you.  If you were the OP, I would do my best to satisfy *your* requirements.   In this case, you have a sense of being aggrieved that I cannot sensibly remedy.

Comment: @jgbelacqua its all good. I have no ill will. I can agree your answer did become more detailed after time. Either way good job :)